# Executing tsc from `jest --watch`

Tags: typescript, jestjs, watch, tty, esbuild

In my monorepo, I am using esbuild to run tests rapidly using `npx jest --watch` but when I add a `tsc` command to the set of tests that runs, the watch console hangs and becomes non-responsive.

I would like to run `tsc` in parallel so that I do, eventually, get notified that there is a compiler error, a few seconds after the test results have reported rapidly (esbuild skips the typescript types and just runs the javascript).

My approach to spawn `tsc` in parallel works without watch but I can't get it to function with `--watch`. It causes a hang of the interactive terminal associated with `jest --watch`, maybe to do with the `stdio:"inherit"`. However without the stdio option, I can't see the output.

What am I missing?

My top-level `jest.config.js` currently looks like this which targets three distinct test suites within the monorepo. It works well with `--watch`. I can run and re-run tests this way using the interactive console ...

```js
module.exports = {
  projects: [
    "<rootDir>/modules/task-editor-logic",
    "<rootDir>/modules/express-vault",
    "<rootDir>/modules/vault-memory",
    // {
    //   globalTeardown: "./check.js",
    // },
  ],
  reporters: ["default", "jest-summary-reporter"],
};
```

A `check` script is declared in package.json as simply `"check": "tsc". I can uncomment the code above to run the` globalTeardown` task which causes check to be run for each run of the test suite.

The source of the teardown task is as below. It correctly succeeds if the code compiles and fails otherwise.

Running it manually as `node check.js` runs the `check` npm script from the console successfully. Running it manually via `npx jest` also works (it runs the `globalTeardown` as a test project). The jest run completes and returns as you would expect.

However, running it via `npx jest --watch` causes a hang and the console of the interactive runner becomes non-responsive requiring a CTRL+C to kill it.

Is there some way to invoke the `pnpm run check` shell command that plays nicer with the `jest --watch` harness and tty?

```js
// check.js
const util = require("util");
const promiseExecSync = util.promisify(require("child_process").execSync);

async function runCheck() {
  return promiseExecSync("pnpm run check", { stdio: "inherit" });
}

module.exports = runCheck;

if (require.main === module) {
  runCheck();
}
```

Comment: I have just noticed that there are some errors arising when the `globalTeardown` project is uncommented, which may be to do with some project defaults - e.g. it's attempting to run all `.test.ts` files inside that project target, while the `globalTeardown` isn't configured properly to run those suites (that's why they are separate projects with their own jest.config.js). So it might be that I need to work out how to have a NOOP jest project, which does nothing but run the globalTeardown script. Maybe with a file pattern that matches nothing.

Comment: I am trying an alternative of creating an actual jest `test.js` file which calls the typescript compiler and which fails if the compilation fails. However changing the final project structure to read ```{ displayName: "Compile Typescript", testMatch: ["./check.test.js"], }``` doesn't seem to execute the test at all.